# Eigenvectors of large symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, symbolic, linear-algebra

I have large symbolic matrix of order 32 x 32  given as

```
({
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/
   2, (j γ)/2, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, (
   j γ)/2, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, (
   j γ)/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, j/2, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, (
   j γ)/2, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0,
    0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, j/2, 
   0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, j/2, 
   0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, j/
   2, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, (j γ)/2, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 
   0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, j/2, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0,
    0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, (j γ)/2, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2,
    0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   j/2, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, j/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, j/2, j/2, 0},
  {0, j/2, j/2, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {(j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {(j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, (j γ)/2, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {(j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, (j γ)/2, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0},
  {(j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, j/2, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 
   j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 
   0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, (
   j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, j/
   2, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, (
   j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, (
   j γ)/2, 0, 0, j/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, (j γ)/2, 0, (
   j γ)/2, (j γ)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 })
```

But it is unable to produce eigenvectors after running the command for three hours.
How i should tackle the situation?

Comment: `Eigenvectors` returns a result in 15 seconds for me.

Comment: george2079 how? may be you find Eigenvalues not Eigenvectors. Please confirm.

Comment: LUDecomposition[myMatrix] states that myMatrix is singular.

Comment: David G. Stork but it is giving the eigenvalues.

Comment: @george2079 Eigenvectors takes 100 seconds for me if I factor out `j`.  `Eigenvalues` is instantaneous.  I have a 2.6 i7 processor in a Mac.  What machine are you using?

Comment: I should say I have 32GB ram. (dual core xeon / windows ) I'd guess this is a memory intensive procedure and the time will go way up if you are disc swapping.  Factoring the `j` didn't make much difference for me, by the way.

Comment: @george2079 You're right, factoring out `j` makes little difference.  `MaxMemoryUsed` gives 64 MB, which is very little.

Comment: @george2079 I noticed some big performance differences for some operations betweens OSs (usually Linux is faster than Windows, which is faster than Mac).  In this case it took 96 s on Linux on the same machine.  It's strange that the timing differs so much between our computers.  The calculation doesn't use much memory.

Comment: @george2079 In Mathematica 9 it takes only 19 seconds.

Comment: @george2079 can you email me the eigenvectors output on the following address usmanqau@hotmail.com it will be agreat help for me.

Comment: @george2079 thank you alot for helping.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:**

In Mathematica 9.0.1 this takes only 19 seconds on first evaluation and 10 seconds on subsequent evaluations.  The results returned by M9 and M10 are equivalent but not given in identical form.

**Update:**

While I was writing this I tried `Eigenvectors[m]`, which finished in 100 seconds on my machine.  I'm leaving the `NullSpace`-based method below because it allows getting at least *some* eigenvectors symbolically even when getting *all* of them would be too slow.

`Eigenvectors[mat]` (i.e. not factoring our `j`) runs in the same time.

I'm using Mathematica 10.0.1 on OS X.

---

**Old answer:**

I don't know how `Eigenvectors` works in the symbolic case so I don't know why it takes long.  But I was able to get the solution in reasonable time using `NullSpace`.

First notice that `j` is just a constant factor, so let's get rid of it to make Mathematica's job easier.  Assuming that `mat` is your matrix,

```
m = mat/j;
```

Eigenvalues are found easily:

```
evs = Union@Eigenvalues[m]
```

Then let's use `NullSpace` for the eigenvectors:

```
Monitor[
 eigenvectors = Join @@ Table[
     NullSpace[
      m - DiagonalMatrix@ConstantArray[evs[[i]], Length[m]]],
     {i, Length[evs]}
     ];,
 i
]
```

This took a couple of minutes on my machine but it did finish.  `Monitor` is useful for watching the progress.

Comment: Slowdown from Mathematica 9 to 10 is related to changes intended to address [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42612/symbolic-linearsolve-is-slower-different-after-upgrading-to-mathematica-9).

Answer (score 1):

the result of `Eigenvalues[m]`:  ( using `g` instead of `\[gamma]` )

```
{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,g^2,0,0,0,0,0,-g,0,0,-g,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,g,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-g,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,g,0,0,0,0,-1,-g,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,g,0,0,-1,-g,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{g^(-2),0,0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,g^(-1),0,0,0,0,0,-1,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,g^(-1),0,0,0,0,-1,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,g^(-1),0,0,-1,-g^(-1),0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,0,0,
-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,0,-1,g^(-1),0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,-1,g^(-1),0,0,0,0,1,
0,0},{0,g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,
-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,
-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,-1,g^(-1),0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,
1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,
0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,0},{0,0,0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,0,-1,g^(-1),0,0,
0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,0,0,-1,
g^(-1),0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,
-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),-(Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g)),0,0,Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),Sqrt[1+g^2]/(Sqrt[2]*g),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-g^(-1),0,0,-1,g^(-1),0,0,1,0,0,
0,0},{0,-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,
-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,-(g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),
0,0,-(1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2])),g/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),0,1/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[1+g^2]),-(1/(Sqrt[2]Sqrt[1+g^2])),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,0},{0,(-8(1-3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(-98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(-189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(-535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^2*(-94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),
(16*(1-6*g^12+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^10*(-226+6*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^8*(-1807+124*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-182+125*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^6*(-3640+509*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(-1916+531*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^3*
(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,(-1+3*g^6-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(29-8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(41-3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/
(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,0,
(-8*(-10-3*g^8+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^6*(-71+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(-219+26*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-129+35*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),
(-8*(1-3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(-98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(-189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(-535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^2*(-94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,0,
(-2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,
(-2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),
(-2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,
-(1-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(6*g^2),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,
(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),
(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,1},
{(-32*(16*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-2411+16*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+75*g^8*(-1271+137*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^2*(-830+403*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
18*g^6*(-6106+1077*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^4*(-5469+1546*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-30350+1691*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(-16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(-16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(-16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(-16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
((3+3*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]])/(2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
0,1,1,0},{0,(8*(1-3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(-98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(-189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(-535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^2*(-94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),
(-16*(1-6*g^12+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^10*(-226+6*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^8*(-1807+124*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-182+125*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^6*(-3640+509*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(-1916+531*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^3*
(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,(1-3*g^6+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-41+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-29+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/
(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,0,
(8*(-10-3*g^8+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^6*(-71+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(-219+26*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-129+35*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),
(8*(1-3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(-98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(-189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(-535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^2*(-94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*(-5-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,0,
(2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,
(2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),
(2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])),0,
-(1-g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(6*g^2),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,
(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),
(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,(4+13*g^2+g^4-2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3-3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,1},
{(32*(16*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-2411+16*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+75*g^8*(-1271+137*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^2*(-830+403*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
18*g^6*(-6106+1077*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^4*(-5469+1546*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-30350+1691*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(16*(-761*g^14+243*(-1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(-18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(-20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(-21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(-102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(-70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(Sqrt[5+5*g^2-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]*(-3-3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(2*(-2-2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
-(-3+g^6+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(-29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(-41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4-Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]-g^2*(-8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
0,1,1,0},{0,(-8*(-1+3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^2*(94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),
(-16*(-1+6*g^12+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^10*(226+6*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^8*(1807+124*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(182+125*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^6*(3640+509*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(1916+531*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^3*
Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,-(-1+3*g^6+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(41+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(29+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/
(3*g^2*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,0,
(-8*(10+3*g^8+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^6*(71+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(219+26*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(129+35*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(g*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),
(-8*(-1+3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g^2*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,0,
(-2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,
(-2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),
(-2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,
(-1+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(6*g^2),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,
(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),
(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,1},
{(-32*(-16*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(2411+16*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+75*g^8*(1271+137*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^2*(830+403*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
18*g^6*(6106+1077*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^4*(5469+1546*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(30350+1691*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(-16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(-16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(-16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(-16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
-((3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]])/(2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
0,1,1,0},{0,(8*(-1+3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^2*(94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),
(16*(-1+6*g^12+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^10*(226+6*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^8*(1807+124*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(182+125*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
g^6*(3640+509*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(1916+531*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(3*g^2*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^3*
Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,(-1+3*g^6+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^4*(41+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(29+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/
(3*g^2*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,0,
(8*(10+3*g^8+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^6*(71+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(219+26*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(129+35*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(g*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),
(8*(-1+3*g^10+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^8*(98+3*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^4*(189+38*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^6*(535+47*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(94+51*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g^2*(5+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^2*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,0,
(2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,
(2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),
(2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/(g*(3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]]),0,
(-1+g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(6*g^2),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,
(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),
(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,(4+13*g^2+g^4+2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])/
(9*g+9*g^3+3*g*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]),0,0,1},
{(32*(-16*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(2411+16*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+75*g^8*(1271+137*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^2*(830+403*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
18*g^6*(6106+1077*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^4*(5469+1546*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(30350+1691*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
(16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(16*(761*g^14+243*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^12*(18365+697*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+9*g^6*(20275+4088*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(8247+4308*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+
3*g^4*(21725+6801*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^10*(102917+8180*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+3*g^8*(70547+9227*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])))/
(3*g*(5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])^(9/2)*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,
((3+3*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])*Sqrt[5+5*g^2+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]])/(2*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
(-g^6+3*(1+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^4*(29+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4])+g^2*(41+8*Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))/(6*g*(2+2*g^4+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]+g^2*(8+Sqrt[1+34*g^2+g^4]))),0,0,1,
0,1,1,0}}
```